# Why Imacros is hanging on str with DATASOURCE?

Tags: imacros

```
    !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60
    SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 5
    SET !ERRORIGNORE yes
    SET !REPLAYSPEED MEDIUM
    SET !DATASOURCE Group.txt
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
    SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
    URL GOTO=url/{{!COL1}}
```

Script runs, no errors, but it's hanging on string SET !DATASOURCE Group.txt

What is wrang? How can I debug iim scripts??

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=9310

http://wiki.imacros.net/AlertFox_allowed_iMacros_commands

Google Chrome doesn't allow Chrome extensions to access the file system. That is the reason why macros are stored as encoded javascript bookmarks. For the same reason working with CSV isn't possible.